# Problema con migraciones en Mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

estoy empezando a usar ASP.NET MVC 5, he hecho un programa que almacena películas en una BBDD (como el ejemplo que viene [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started))

Pero llega un punto en el que tienes que empezar a utilizar migraciones, según el documento basta con borrar el archivo .mdf y añadir la siguiente línea de código: 
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext

Pero al hacer esto me sale un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a hacer un "Enabled-migrations" y tampoco sale.
He reducido la versión de Entity Framework y me salía otro error pero aun así nada.

Dejo el [proyecto](https://mega.nz/#!vYwkRIrQ!c3rCm3LKVCHnSKJANzQaJh_1QKx2H1dZWfpiKxN1iLw) por aquí por si acaso.

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Segun el error no encuentra ninguna ruta, estas seguro que estas ejecutando el comando en el sitio correcto o te falta añadir alguna ruta?

Comment: Si, la ruta esta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer hay algun error con Entity Framework aqui lo solucionan haciendo una reinstalacion, dejo el enlace

https://entityframework.net/es/knowledge-base/14410987/codigo-de-entity-framework-primer-error-de-migracion

Comment: Ya probé a hacerlo y no me funcionó, pero gracias de todas formas.